# How can I make the LyX - Table of contents (TOC) page be empty after the end of the TOC and not continue with the other pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I have created a TOC in my LyX by simply using the TOC from the Insert menu.

I have found that after the TOC ends the rest of the page is not blank as expected, but rather what I wrote comes directly afterwards.

How can I tell LyX to leave the rest of the page blank ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the cursor behind the TOC and then  `Insert->Format->newpage`